# does uniform convergence imply convergence in distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space, and $f_n$ is a sequence of complex valued measurable functions converging uniformly to $f$.
Is it then true for every almost every $\lambda > 0$, that $\mu{(\{x: |f_n(x)| > \lambda\})}$ converges to $ \mu(\{x:|f(x)| > \lambda\}) $?

If it's not true, are there conditions that can be given so that it becomes true?

Edit: Someone has pointed out a counter example for non infinite measure spaces, is it true for finite measure spaces?

Comment: What is meant by converges almost everywhere? Denote $\alpha_n =$  μ({x:|fn(x)|>λ}) and $\alpha=$ μ({x:|f(x)|>λ}). Then $(\alpha_n)$ is just a sequence of real numbers while $\alpha$ is a real number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a finite measure space even point-wise converegence implies convergence in measure.

A simple counter-example in the case of an  infinite measure is $f_n(x)=1+\frac  1n$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $f_n(x)=1-\frac  1n$ on $(-\infty, 0)$. In this case $f_n \to 1$ uniformly, $\mu (|f_n| >1)=\infty$ for all $n$ but $\mu (|f| >1)=0$.

Comment: This is not a counter-example. Clearly, for each $c>0$, $\{x\mid|f(x)|>c\}=\emptyset$
and hence $m\left(\{x\mid|f(x)|>c\}\right)=0$. However, $\{x\mid|f_{n}(x)|>c\}$
is also an empty set for sufficiently large $n$, hence the measure
is also zero.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Thank you for the comment. I have modified the example.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you explain why the claim is true in finite measure spaces? it's not quite the same thing as convergence in measure